# Instance variable changing value when another instance of same class is modified, Python-Tkinter

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

The `Point` class has an instance variable `point`, which keeps tabs of each unique corner of the polygon. Problem is, when I hover the cursor over the second instance of the class, the `point` variable of the first instance changes. My code,

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk,Canvas
import sys,os,string,time

class Point():
    def __init__(self,root,canvas,pt,radius = 4):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.root = root
        self.point = self.canvas.create_oval(pt[0]-radius,pt[1]-radius,pt[0]+radius,pt[1]+radius,fill = "green", tag = "Point")
        self.canvas.tag_bind("Point","<Enter>",self.enter)
        self.canvas.tag_bind("Point","<Leave>",self.leave)
    def enter(self,event):
        print(self.point)
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(CURRENT,fill="blue")
        self.loc = 1
    def leave(self,event):
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(CURRENT,fill="green")

root = Tk()
root.title("Poly Draw")
canvas = Canvas(root,width = 256, height = 256, borderwidth = 1)
pt = [100,100]
point = Point(root,canvas,pt)
point2 = Point(root,canvas,[150,150])
print(point.point)
print(point2.point)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

When you run the above piece of code you will see that the instance variable `self.point` is changing for the first instance when I hover over the second instance(I am printing `self.point` when cursor enters the widget). Noted that, before I run the `mainloop()` the instance variable is correct.

Comment: @REVOLUTION: This `self.canvas.tag_bind("Point", "<Enter>", self.enter)` overwrites the previous `self.canvas.tag_bind("Point", "<Enter>", self.enter)`. Therefore only the last, which ist `iid == 2` get the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're binding the tag "Point" sequentially, so only the last one is active.

I think you instead want to bind to the item id, not to the (non-unique) tag.

If so, change the binding instead to:

> ```
> def __init__(self,root,canvas,pt,radius = 4):
>     self.canvas = canvas
>     self.root = root
>     self.point = self.canvas.create_oval(pt[0]-radius,pt[1]-radius,pt[0]+radius,pt[1]+radius,fill = "green", tag = "Point")
>     self.canvas.tag_bind(self.point,"<Enter>",self.enter)
>     self.canvas.tag_bind(self.point,"<Leave>",self.leave)
> ```

Comment: Yup! Worked like a charm! I actually had a couple of those points in the class, in the original code. So I thought why not just bind them with a tag(wrong approach). Finally, I had to bind each of them individually, in a for loop. Thanks!